# About the like_status with PHP programming

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-apps, facebook-canvas

When I try to use `['signed_request']` in PHP, I can't get `[page][liked] / Page ID` value. 
I only can get `[algorithm]`, `[issued_at]`, `[user]`, `[country]`, `[locale]`, `[age]` values from `['signed_request']`.

I have created "users_like" Permission in the App's Auth Dialog page. I have set up a Canvas page.

Please help me find out the problem and solution.

P.S. I want to set up  a landing page which can check the user whether like it or not.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't add the app to your page and *not* accessing the app from that tab!

Comment: I have added the app and set as a landing page. But the current app does not have the checking procedure.

Comment: Hi, ifaour:
if the app does not go live in fan page, can it support page liked_status?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by `liked_status`. It's really simple, if an app is loaded from within a page tab...it'll receive an extra parameter `page` with a `liked` value either set or not! Have a look at my [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/determine-if-the-user-likes-fan-of-your-page-when-landing-on-your-page-tab/29/).

Comment: Hi, ifaour,
Thank you,I knew the problem after I looked at your tutorial page. It is because I set the page tag and canvas as a same URL and location. Page_like only work with "Page Tag".

Comment: ummm, okay...but you can always use the same url for canvas and tab. Checking if the request is coming from a page you would change your app logic accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// create the Facebook Graph SDK object
require_once('facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'=>'xxxxxxxx', // replace with your value
    'secret'=>'xxxxxxxx' // replace with your value
));
$signedRequest = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

// Inspect the signed request
if($signedRequest['page']['liked'] == 1){ //Do your stuff here }
```

That is all that's required, you don't need any permissions.

EDIT: Also, make sure that you are actually trying to access a page, not, for example, an app canvas.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried the similar code before but still failure.

Comment: I want to make a landing page which can check whether the user like it or not.

Comment: Thank you, Leo. I have solved the problem. The problem is I set the canvas and page tag as a same URL and location. ['Page']['liked'] only work in "page tag".